# Array from php to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

I have a php file that I gather data on an array and I need to send this data to an external javascript file.
I have read that I need to encode data to JSON format and echo the variable stored, then I try to use this variable on the javascript file but I get an error "Can't find variable: jArray"
What I do wrong?

file.php

```
<?php $playerNames_new = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$_POST["playerNo"]; $i++) {
    $j = $i+1;
    echo "<form name=\"input\" action=\"#\" method=\"POST\">Player Name $j: <input type=\"text\" name=\"playerName[]\" value=\"\"><br/>";
        $playerNames_new[$i] = $_REQUEST['playerName'];
}


?> 
<script type="text/javascript">var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($playerNames_new); ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// global variables
var playerNames = jArray;});
```

Comment: Looks like it should be working. What do you see when you do view source where `var jArray = ` is?

Comment: json_encode is going to create a json object, if I'm not mistake. I'd try a simpler approach first and try to put a string from php into javascript, and see if the scripts.js would read it. Also you need to wrap your jArray, so it would be `var jArray = '<?='String Test'>'`

Comment: I am still getting the same error, even if I put a single variable.

Comment: Just for kicks try calling it `window.jArray` in both locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
<script> var php = <?php echo json_encode([1, 2 ,3]); ?>;</script>
<script src="s.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script> var php = <?php echo json_encode([1, 2 ,3]); ?>;</script>
<script> console.log(php); </script>
```

[image: the console log]

Comment: @ToroLoco that's great, if you don't mind could you update your question with the problem you solved, usually helps other people out that might be in the same bind.

Comment: Actually it was correct how I had written it. But I didn't mention that from the php page that I would like to pass the data to the js file there was another php page that was intermediate. So I had to pass the data first to the other php page and then to the JavaScript.